# How should I go about creating a component that contains a mat-form-field and input?

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-reactive-forms

I'm working on a project that uses a lot of nested reactive forms and I want to create a control that wraps both a Mat-Form-Field and the input into one component, but when I try it in my form I keep getting errors.

I think the issue is with the control being in an array as it seems to work when on its own.

Currently with the code below I'm getting the following error message BasicInputComponent.html:2 ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'firstName'

I've also tried using ControlValueAccessor, but I'm not sure that this is the correct way of doing things either and when I did try it I couldn't get the mat-from-field to recognize that it wasn't valid.

I realize the example is quite basic, but I really need the control to be usable in form arrays so that I can use it in other places in the system.

Child component html:

```
<mat-form-field floatLabel="never" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid">
    <input matInput #input [placeholder]="placeholder" [type]="type" [attr.maxlength]="maxlength" type="text" [formControlName]="controlName"/>
    <mat-hint *ngIf="maxlength" align="end">{{input.value?.length || 0}}/{{maxlength}}</mat-hint>
</mat-form-field>
```

Child Component ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-basic-input',
    templateUrl: './basic-input.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./basic-input.component.css'],
    viewProviders: [{ provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: FormGroupDirective }]
})
export class BasicInputComponent { 

    @Input() placeholder: string;
    @Input() controlName: string;
    @Input() maxlength: number | null;

    constructor() {}
}
```

Parent html:

```
<form [formGroup]="vehicle">
    <div formArrayName="occupants" *ngFor="let occupant of vehicle.get('occupants')['controls']; let i = index;">
        <div [formGroupName]="i">
              <app-basic-input placeholder="First Name" controlName="firstName" maxlength="25"></app-basic-input>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Parent ts:

```
    vehicle= this.fb.group({
        occupants: this.fb.array([
            this.fb.group({
                firstName: ['', Validators.required],
                lastName: ['', Validators.required]
            })
        ])
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to split this line in **parent.html**:

```
...
<div formArrayName="occupants" *ngFor="let occupant of vehicle.get('occupants')['controls']; let i = index;">
...
</div>
...
```

into

```
...
<div formArrayName="occupants">
  <div *ngFor="let occupant of vehicle.get('occupants')['controls']; let i = index;">
  ...
  </div>
</div>
...
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to make any difference, I still get the same error